# Google Maps API, Hangs when Loading Onion.js (Started Yesterday)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Not sure if something has changed in the API but since yesterday, when loading multiple markers all of my demos and over 5000 buyers sites hang once it gets to loading onion.js from what I can see in the network tab of the browser dev tools.

This is the script I've been using to do all the heavy lifting on loading and displaying multiple markers, with custom infowindows and clustering. Whenever I take this out it the site won't hang but of course it won't show the markers on the map, my single marker maps which don't use this script load up just fine.

I know it has to be something I'm using in this file that's causing the issue, I searched and couldn't find any updates from Google themselves about changes to anything, any help is much appreciated!

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**
(ct.mapping.js is commented out otherwise the page won't load, uncomment to see issue):

http://contempothemes.com/re7-dev/map-test/index.html

Search results with multiple markers (not working):

http://wordpressmu-96733-274081.cloudwaysapps.com/re7-dev/?search-listings=true

Single Marker Map (works):

http://wordpressmu-96733-274081.cloudwaysapps.com/re7-dev/listings/escada-apartments/

This is the ct.mapping.js file:

```
/**
* Contempo Mapping
*
* @package WP Pro Real Estate 7
* @subpackage JavaScript
*/

var estateMapping = (function () {
var self = {},
    marker_list = [],
    current_marker = 0,
    open_info_window = null,
    x_center_offset = 0, // x,y offset in px when map gets built with marker bounds
    y_center_offset = 0,
    x_info_offset = -0, // x,y offset in px when map pans to marker -- to accomodate infoBubble
    y_info_offset = -180;

function build_marker(latlng, property) {

    var mapPin = '';
    if(property['commercial'] == 'commercial') {
        var mapPin= property.siteURL+'/images/map-pin-com.png';
    } else if(property['land'] == 'land') {
        var mapPin= property.siteURL+'/images/map-pin-land.png';
    } else {
        var mapPin= property.siteURL+'/images/map-pin-res.png';
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: self.map, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        draggable: false,
        flat: true,
        icon: mapPin,   
        position: latlng
    });

    marker_list.push(marker);

    self.bounds.extend(latlng);
    self.map.fitBounds(self.bounds);
    self.map.setCenter(convert_offset(self.bounds.getCenter(), x_center_offset, y_center_offset));

    var residentialString = '';
    if(property['commercial'] != 'commercial') {
        var residentialString=''+property.bed+' | '+property.bath+' | ';
    }

    if(property['contactpage'] == 'contactpage') {

        if(property['thumb'] != '') {

            var contentString =
            '<div class="infobox">'+
            '<div class="info-image"'+
                '<figure>'+
                    '<img src="'+property.thumb+'" height="250" width="250" />'+
                '</figure>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="listing-details">'+
                '<header>'+
                    '<h4 class="marT0">'+property.title+'</h4>'+
                '</header>'+
                '<p class="price marB0"><strong><a href="//maps.google.com/maps?daddr='+property.street+'" target="_blank">Driving Directions</a></strong></p>'+
            '</div>';

        } else {

            var contentString =
            '<div class="infobox">'+
            '<div class="listing-details">'+
                '<header>'+
                    '<h4 class="marT0">'+property.title+'</h4>'+
                '</header>'+
                '<p class="price marB0"><strong><a href="//maps.google.com/maps?daddr='+property.street+'" target="_blank">Driving Directions</a></strong></p>'+
            '</div>';

        }

    } else {

        var contentString =
        '<div class="infobox">'+
        '<div class="info-image"'+
            '<figure>'+
                '<a href="'+property.permalink+'">'+
                    property.thumb+
                '</a>'+
            '</figure>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="listing-details">'+
            '<header>'+
                '<h4 class="marT5 marB0"><a href="'+property.permalink+'">'+property.title+'</a></h4>'+
                '<p class="location muted marB5">'+property.city+', '+property.state+'&nbsp;'+property.zip+'</p>'+
            '</header>'+
            '<p class="price marB0"><strong>'+property.fullPrice+'</strong></p>'+
        '</div>';

    }

    var imagesURL = property.siteURL;

    var infobox = new InfoBox({
        content: contentString,
        disableAutoPan: true,
        maxWidth: 0,
        alignBottom: true,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size( -125, -64 ),
        zIndex: null,
        closeBoxMargin: "8px 0 -20px -20px",
        closeBoxURL: imagesURL+'/images/infobox-close.png',
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        if(open_info_window) open_info_window.close();


            infobox.open(self.map, marker);
            self.map.panTo(convert_offset(this.position, x_info_offset, y_info_offset));
            open_info_window = infobox;

    });
}

// Next/Previous Marker Navigation

var ct_map_next = function() {
    current_marker++;
    if (current_marker > marker_list.length){
        current_marker = 1;
    }
    while(marker_list[current_marker-1].visible === false) {
        current_marker++;
        if(current_marker > marker_list.length) {
            current_marker = 1;
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker_list[current_marker-1], 'click');
}

var ct_map_prev = function() {
    current_marker--;
    if (current_marker < 1) {
        current_marker = marker_list.length;
    }
    while(marker_list[current_marker-1].visible === false) {
        current_marker--;
        if(current_marker > marker_list.length) {
            current_marker = 1;
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker_list[current_marker-1], 'click');
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('ct-gmap-next').addEventListener('click',function () {
        ct_map_next();
    });

    document.getElementById('ct-gmap-prev').addEventListener('click',function () {
        ct_map_prev();
    });
}

function geocode_and_place_marker(property) {
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var address = property.street+', '+property.city+' '+property.state+', '+property.zip;

       //If latlong exists build the marker, otherwise geocode then build the marker
       if (property['latlong'] && property['latlong'].length>1) {
           var lat = parseFloat(property['latlong'].split(',')[0]),
                lng = parseFloat(property['latlong'].split(',')[1]);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            build_marker(latlng, property);

       } else {
           geocoder.geocode({ address : address }, function( results, status ) {
               if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                    build_marker(latlng, property);
                }
            });
        }
}

function init_canvas_projection() {
    function CanvasProjectionOverlay() {}
    CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.constructor = CanvasProjectionOverlay;
    CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){};
    CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){};
    CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){};

    self.canvasProjectionOverlay = new CanvasProjectionOverlay();
    self.canvasProjectionOverlay.setMap(self.map);
}

function convert_offset(latlng, x_offset, y_offset) {
    var proj = self.canvasProjectionOverlay.getProjection();
    var point = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlng);
    point.x = point.x + x_offset;
    point.y = point.y + y_offset;
    return proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
}

self.init_property_map = function (properties, defaultmapcenter) {

    if(ctMapGlobal['mapStyle'] != 'default') {
        var options = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(defaultmapcenter.mapcenter),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: true,
            styles: [{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#acbcc9"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"color":"#f2e5d4"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5c6c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e4d7c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#fbfaf7"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5dac6"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},{"featureType":"road"},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{},{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]}]
        };
    } else {
        var options = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(defaultmapcenter.mapcenter),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: true
        };
    }

    /* Marker Clusters */
    var markerClustererOptions = {
        ignoreHidden: true,
        maxZoom: 14,
        styles: [{
            textColor: '#ffffff',
            url: property.siteURL+'/images/cluster-icon.png',
            height: 48,
            width: 48
        }]
    };

    self.map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), options );
    self.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    init_canvas_projection();

    //wait for idle to give time to grab the projection (for calculating offset)
    var idle_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'idle', function() {
        for (i=0;i<properties.length;i++) {
            geocode_and_place_marker(properties[i]);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(self.map, marker_list, markerClustererOptions);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(idle_listener);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
    });

}

return self;
}());
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using?  The experimental version just changed.

Comment: I'm using v3 of the API

Comment: Which version of v3 (experimental, released, frozen)?

Comment: Using the released version.

Comment: I know it has to be something small…

Comment: Possibly a syntax change, I've already tried stripping out various pieces like the infobox, clustering, etc…no change though still the same.

Comment: A change to the frozen version should get your page working again.  But that will only last for about 9 months (until the next API release), so you will need to find the problem eventually.

Comment: Added ?v=3.29 which is the current frozen version and still the same result.

Comment: Related issue in the issue tracker [Bug: Javascript error - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/23/2/intl/en_gb/onion.js](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827696)

Comment: Loads for a bit then hits onion.js and kills the page…

Comment: Read through that thread, all related to IE and browser modes, this is across all browsers including Chrome itself.

Comment: Do you notice anything in the JS pasted above that might be deprecated or causing an issue with overlays?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (you may discover the issue creating that).

Comment: I've put together a basic HTML page with just the map and JSON list, http://contempothemes.com/re7-dev/map-test/index.html

Comment: If I add the ct.mapping.js file which is pasted above it just completely kills the page from loading, once I remove it I get the estatemapping undefined since its part of the JS file, so it just spins, here's a screenshot https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0H1d200F10443c0n3s47/Image%202018-02-14%20at%2011.35.44%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=670313

Comment: So its 100% something within that file that's causing the onion.js file to choke that's been changed since yesterday within the API, I just don't know what?

Comment: If you didn't already, you should file an issue at:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue since yesterday. As per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827696 , setting v=3.22 in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEYv=3.22 fixed it.

Comment: Note that the available versions are 3.30 3.31 and 3.32. Requesting v=3.23 you actually get 3.30. In this case you should use v=3.31 which will become the frozen version in about 3 months. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Comment: Tried that same problem…

Comment: Actually using this fixed the issue //maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&#038;v=3.22&#038;ver=1.0

Comment: Found out its an issue with the latest v3.32 which is experimental,
stable 3.31 works beautifully so something is messed up on Googles side

Comment: Neither of the options above worked. *Suddenly*, after a few hours of testing and failures, it started working again only referencing this script `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&libraries=places`

Comment: This fixed things for us as well, I added '&v=3.31' to our script import